# Digital Twin: what is the scientific status of outcomes of simulation?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Digital twins are representations (usually by means of software) of some aspects of physical systems. They are meant to enable the prediction or research of those systems - be these cities, organizations, or natural phenomena such as climate change.

If building a simulation of some system - how shall we view the simulation's outcome? Is the outcome scientific as if it were the result of the system represented by the simulation? What is the epistemological status of the results of simulations? Are they like speculations/conjectures? Are they equal to the results of scientific experiments? What are they?

Comment: idk how much is the twin worth?

Answer (score 2):

A simulation's outcome is a prediction. One has to be well aware that it's not perfect. It doesn't replace testing with actual hardware, but instead makes it much easier, faster, and therefore cheaper to find problems before testing actual Hardware.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting idea. I'm mainly interested in the ethical side to it. What if a human had a high quality *digital twin*. We could conduct toxicological/pharmaceutical/psychological/etc. tests without worrying about right and wrong ("no one" would be *harmed*, not even *animal trials* would be necessary)

Second, simulations, one of its pros, is that it permits *time compression*. I believe a *universe simulation* from the Big Bang (13.8 **billion** years) was completed in a *few hours/day* (I forget which). We could *simulate* evolution itself; just imagine how long a real-world *experiment* in evolution will take (a thousand, a million, generations will need to be studied).

Third, we could modify specific parameters (re *scientific experiment*) and observe their effects.

How *reliable* are simulations?

They're based on some set of models abstracted from the world and to the extent these are good, the simulations are. However, *cum grano salis* - what we *don't know* will matter ... a lot, we might've missed something really important.

Fun fact: In World of Warcraft there was a *glitch* in the program and one spell mimicked an infection. Lo and behold, there was an *epidemic* which Wikipedia claims was a near-perfect representation of real-world epidemics like e.g. Covid-19 for example.

Answer (score 2):

A simulation is a model of a system, usually incorporating a large number of simplifying assumptions. The output of the simulation is a prediction of how the real system might behave. The extent to which the output faithfully represents the behaviour of the system depends upon the validity of the simplifying assumptions, as well as on how carefully the model has been implemented.

For example, we know the equations of quantum mechanics can very precisely model the behaviour of microscopic particles, but it is practically impossible to find solutions to those equations for cases in which large numbers of particles are interacting with each other. If you imagine a solid state diode used to drive a laser, it will contain far too many particles to create a model in which the behaviour of each individual particle is taken into account. Instead, we model the behaviour of the laser by making a number of assumptions that drastically simplify the equations that must be solved- if it is a good model it will accurately predict the behaviour of the laser. If we find that a model generates good results (ie ones that are with observations of the real system), we can have some degree of confidence in it and we might therefore be prepared to assume that its predictions are valid.

The outcome of a simulation is not in itself a conjecture or speculation. In effect, the simplifying assumptions built into the model are a form of hypothesis, in that the builder of the model is proposing that their assumptions are valid, and they test that by running the model. You might find it useful to consider the output of a model to be a kind of estimate about how the system might behave.

Answer (score 1):

A simulation is essentially just a visualization of a theory + some hardware quirks on of the simulating system.

The simulation is neither perceiving nor acting and is therefore independent of the "real world" it is therefore not an experiment but rather a "what if" scenario. All that it does is answer the question of "what would it mean for system X if we assume that our current model of reality is true and situation Y happens".

So in consequence the result of that simulation is just a visualization of what the implication of your model actually are, however they still operate under the axioms of that model and NOT under the constraints of the real world. So technically you've just outsourced the computationally heavy part of thinking through your theory.

And as said on top of that you might have some additional quirks due to hardware and software architecture. Like the fact that the software forces you to move from a continuous world to a discrete one. Like there are infinitely many glimpses in a second but there's only so much computational power and memory so that you can only compute a snapshot every now and then rather than a continuous stream, which might be ok, but which might also produce artifacts that exist only in the simulation and not in the thing that is simulated.