# Are simulation based tests / experiments also just types of augmented hyper-reality?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, epistemology, ontology, scientific-realism, experiment

Questions: Are simulation based-tests / experiments just types of augmented hyper-reality?

Background: What I mean here is that the types of tests / experiments here are simulation based so this is why I bring up hyper-reality. None of these specific types of test / experiments are the same as ‘monitors’ of reality.

Comment: Why do you say that tests and experiments are simulation based? If I test the tyre pressure on my car, or the voltage of a battery, or the temperature of my oven, or if I perform an experiment to determine the acceleration due to gravity, in what way am I augmenting hyper-reality?

Comment: @Marcor Ocram Sorry I need to reword it, but not all tests and experiments are simulation based. In your example it would be monitoring reality, and you could call it a test or experiment. However, your examples would be a sort of simulations if they weren’t your actual systems that you were using in real life, like if you tested acceleration due to gravity that would be fine in that region, but it may not represent the real scenario if you were in another region with anomalous gravity.

Comment: Welcome to SE. The question, as I understand it, is fine. But I would suggest that a few specific examples would have made it clearer what you are getting at.

Comment: I feel like this question is similar to this one: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/95213/digital-twin-what-is-the-scientific-status-of-outcomes-of-simulation  But not for sure, since I am unsure what you mean by hyper-reality.